# SharePoint 2013 document library: default view no longer selectable from personal view?

Tags: 2013, document-library, view, office-365

I've got a Pages library with several folders in it, and several views configured. I've changed the availability of some views using the per-location displa settings, so that the root level will have different views than any of the subfolders.

- Pages root: View A and view B
- Folders: View "All Documents"

This works flawlessly.

However, when I add a self-made personal view to the mix, something peculiar happens to the default view (All Documents): as long as I'm not actually using my personal view, the views seem to function as expected and mentioned above. But as soon as I select my personal view, I can no longer switch back to my default view. It's simply not listed as an available view any more - views A and B are.

Likewise, when opening a folder that uses the default "All documents" view using the managed metadata navigation folder tree in the quick launch sidebar, I get a blank page and not the default empty folder. The folder tree view disappears as well - even though I'm not actually looking at a page but should be seeing the folder contents.

Is this a possible configuration error (and where to look), or normal behavior? What could be the logic behind this?

The issue has been found on multiple sites.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the configuration of your per-location view settings with respect to the Metadata navigation settings.

When you are on your Personal view, can you check where it is highlighted on your hierarchical navigation control on the left navigation of your list, once identified, go to Per-location view settings and on the left hierarchical navigation which is under 'location to configure', highlight the same folder/content type. Now to your right and select the view for default view (All Documents) from 'Views hidden from this location' and add it to the "Views available at this location". Hopefully this solves the issue.

About your second issue -  You getting a blank page and not the default empty folder on click of a hierarchical navigation control folder, did you try to open the folder in a new tab or new window? 
The folder click triggers an inbuilt javascript function _spNavigateHierarchy that has the information of your view that you have configured it for, it is not a hyperlink that can be opened in a new window or tab.